# How to make a div comparison with next and previous buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, comparison

I'm trying to make sets of div comparisons with next and previous buttons. So, when the next button is clicked "1" should be matched up with "A", "2" with "B", and so forth. The code is working for the first set of div's, but not for the set that it's suppose to be compared with. What do I need to add to make it work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".alldivsSet1 div").each(function(e) {
  if (e != 0)
   $(this).hide();
 });
  
 $(".alldivsSet2 div").each(function(e) {
  if (e != 0)
   $(this).hide();
 });

 $("#next").click(function() {
  if ($(".alldivsSet1 div:visible").next().length != 0)
   $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
  else {
   $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible").hide();
   $(".alldivsSet1 div:first").show();
  }
  return false;
 });

 $("#prev").click(function() {
  if ($(".alldivsSet1 div:visible").prev().length != 0)
   $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
  else {
   $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible").hide();
   $(".alldivsSet1 div:last").show();
  }
  return false;
 });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:arial;
}

div {
  margin:0 0 40px 0;
}

a {
  padding:10px 20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:#ddd;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alldivsSet1">
 <div class="slide1"><b>COMPARISON 1</b> Lorem Ipsum</div>
 <div class="slide2"><b>COMPARISON 2</b> Lorem Ipsum</div>
 <div class="slide3"><b>COMPARISON 3</b> Lorem Ipsum</div>
 <div class="slide4"><b>COMPARISON 4</b> Lorem Ipsum </div>
 <div class="slide5"><b>COMPARISON 5</b> Lorem Ipsum</div>
 <div class="slide6"><b>COMPARISON 6</b> Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="alldivsSet2">
 <div class="slide1"><b>COMPARISON A</b> Ipsum Lorem</div>
 <div class="slide2"><b>COMPARISON B</b> Ipsum Lorem</div>
 <div class="slide3"><b>COMPARISON C</b> Ipsum Lorem</div>
 <div class="slide4"><b>COMPARISON D</b> Ipsum Lorem</div>
 <div class="slide5"><b>COMPARISON E</b> Ipsum Lorem</div>
 <div class="slide6"><b>COMPARISON F</b> Ipsum Lorem</div>
</div>

<a id="prev">PREV</a>
<a id="next">NEXT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".alldivsSet1 div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $(".alldivsSet2 div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function() {
        if ($(".alldivsSet1 div:visible, .alldivsSet2 div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible, .alldivsSet2 div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible, .alldivsSet2 div:visible").hide();
            $(".alldivsSet1 div:first, .alldivsSet2 div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function() {
        if ($(".alldivsSet1 div:visible, .alldivsSet2 div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible, .alldivsSet2 div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".alldivsSet1 div:visible, .alldivsSet2 div:visible").hide();
            $(".alldivsSet1 div:last, .alldivsSet2 div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```